# Override Ansible playbook `serial` from command line

Tags: ansible

We use `serial` in nearly all of our playbooks but there are occasions where we need to make a quick change and it's unnecessary for the Ansible to abide by the `serial` restriction.

Is there a way to override `serial` from the command line with a flag as part of the `ansible-playbook` command?

Code example:

```
- hosts: database
  serial: 1
  become: yes
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can pass a variable from cli with -e flag, and use that to the `serial` attribute. example (adding a default value of 3 in case you dont pass the variable value in cli):

```
- hosts: ping_test
  serial: "{{ serial_number|default(3) }}"
  gather_facts: true
  vars:

  tasks:
    - name: task 1
      debug:
        var: serial_number
```

run as:

`ansible-playbook <playbook file> -e serial_number=1`

sample output (2 executions):

```
[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook -i hosts serial.yml -e serial_number=1

PLAY [ping_test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [task 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "serial_number": "1"
}

PLAY [ping_test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [greenhat]

TASK [task 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [greenhat] => {
    "serial_number": "1"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
greenhat                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]# ansible-playbook -i hosts serial.yml -e serial_number=2

PLAY [ping_test] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [greenhat]
ok: [localhost]

TASK [task 1] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "serial_number": "2"
}
ok: [greenhat] => {
    "serial_number": "2"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
greenhat                   : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   

[root@optima-ansible ILIAS]#
```

Comment: To improve this, default it to whatever serial value you normally wish to run with, that way you only need to override for your special cases: ```serial: {{ serial_val|default(3) }}```.  With that, you don't have to specify a ```-e``` switch at all if you want to run "normal", but in your off-cases, you can ```ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml -e serial_val=8```.

Comment: great tip @MarkR, definitely efficient! (will add it to the answer)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today. I always want the playbook to run with `serial: 1`, but I wanted to run a `--check` against all of them to audit for consistency with the playbook. To get around this, just for use with `--check`, I did the following:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts <(sed '/serial: 1/d' myserialplaybook.yml) --check
```

There are a few things going on here:

- `<( ... )` is treated as a file with contents of the STDOUT from the command inside
- `sed '/serial: 1/d' file.txt` Drops any line with the string `serial: 1` in it.

Therefore, the resulting playbook file run was simply missing the `serial: 1` line altogether and was able to run the `--check` in full parallel as I needed.